# How to open multiple mui DialogProvider dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, frontend

I have a generic DialogProvider that written with MUI and I open all dialog modals with this generic provider.

Code is below.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";
import {
  BooleanValuePaths,
  getValue,
  setValue,
  Paths,
  PathValueType,
  StringValuePaths,
} from "../utils/utils";
import { IAppState, useAppState } from "./app-state";

type BaseType = object;

export class DialogState<T extends BaseType> {
  _data: T;
  _resetFunction?: () => T;
  _touched: BooleanValuePaths<Paths<T>>;
  _error: StringValuePaths<Paths<T>>;
  _formError?: string;
  _initialData: T;

  constructor(dataInitiator: () => T) {
    this._data = dataInitiator();
    this._initialData = dataInitiator();
    this._resetFunction = dataInitiator;
    this._touched = {};
    this._error = {};
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  reset() {
    this._resetFunction?.();
  }

  get data() {
    return this._data;
  }

  get formTouched() {
    const touched = Object.keys(this._touched).find(
      (key) => this._touched[key as Paths<T>],
    );
    return touched;
  }

  setValue<P extends Paths<T>>(path: P, value: PathValueType<T, P>): void {
    setValue(this._data, path, value as any); //TODO remove the "as any", but the typescript has problem
    this._touched[path] = true;
  }

  getValue<P extends Paths<T>>(path: P): PathValueType<T, P> {
    return getValue(this._data, path) as PathValueType<T, P>; //TODO remove the "as PathValueType<T, P>", but the typescript has problem
  }

  isTouched<P extends Paths<T>>(path: P) {
    return this._touched[path];
  }

  errorOf<P extends Paths<T>>(path: P) {
    return this._error[path];
  }

  setErrorOf<P extends Paths<T> | "">(path: P, error: string) {
    this._error[path] = error;
  }

  resetErrors() {
    this._error = {};
  }

  resetTouches() {
    this._touched = {};
  }

  resetData() {
    this._data = this._initialData;
  }

  setFormError(error: string) {
    this._formError = error;
  }
}

function processErrorFunction<T extends BaseType>(
  state: DialogState<T>,
  err: any,
  appState: IAppState,
  errorKeyMap?: { errorKey: string; dataKey: string }[],
) {
  try {
    const json = JSON.parse(err?.message);
    if (Array.isArray(json?.message)) {
      (json.message as any[]).forEach((m) => {
        if (
          typeof m?.property === "string" &&
          typeof m?.constraints === "object"
        ) {
          const msg = Object.keys(m.constraints)
            .map((k) => m.constraints[k])
            .join(", ");
          const dataKey =
            errorKeyMap?.find((erk) => erk.errorKey === m.property)?.dataKey ??
            m.property;
          state.setErrorOf(dataKey, msg);
        }
      });
    } else {
      appState.setSnackMessage({ message: json?.message || "unknown" });
    }
  } catch (_) {
    appState.setSnackMessage({ message: err?.message || "unknown" });
  }
}

export function useDialogStateProvider<T extends BaseType>(
  stateInitiator: () => T,
  saverFunction: (v: T, appState: IAppState) => Promise<any>,
  closeFunction?: (value?: T) => void,
  errorKeyMap?: { errorKey: string; dataKey: string }[],
) {
  const appState = useAppState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const state = React.useMemo(
    () => new DialogState(stateInitiator),
    [stateInitiator],
  );

  const reset = () => {
    state.reset();
  };

  const handleSave = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      state.resetErrors();
      await saverFunction(state.data, appState);
      state.resetTouches();

      if (closeFunction) {
        state.resetData();
        closeFunction(state.data);
        reset();
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      processErrorFunction(state, err, appState, errorKeyMap);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    try {
      if (closeFunction) {
        setLoading(false);
        state.resetErrors();
        state.resetData();
        state.resetTouches();

        closeFunction(state.data);
        reset();
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      processErrorFunction(state, err, appState, errorKeyMap);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return {
    reset,
    state,
    loading,
    handleSave,
    handleClose,
  };
}
interface useDialogStateProviderInterface<T extends BaseType> {
  (stateProvider: () => T): {
    reset: () => void;
    state: DialogState<T>;
    loading: boolean;
    handleSave: () => Promise<void>;
    handleClose?: () => void;
  };
}

export type DialogStateProviderType<T extends BaseType> = ReturnType<
  useDialogStateProviderInterface<T>
>;

export const DialogStateContext =
  React.createContext<DialogStateProviderType<any> | null>(null);

export function DialogStateProvider<
  K extends BaseType,
  T extends DialogStateProviderType<K>,
>({ state, children }: { state: T; children?: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <DialogStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      {children}
    </DialogStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useDialogState<T extends BaseType>() {
  const store = React.useContext(DialogStateContext);
  if (!store) {
    throw new Error("useDialogState must be used within DialogStateProvider");
  }
  return store as DialogStateProviderType<T>;
}
```

Usage is like below:

```
<DialogStateProvider state={taskState}>
  <BaseDialog open={open} handleClose={handleClose} title={title}>
    <AssignedTaskEditor isSubsequent={isSubsequent} />
  </BaseDialog>
</DialogStateProvider>
```

BaseDialog code is this:

```
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogTitle,
  IconButton,
  SxProps,
  Theme,
  useMediaQuery,
  useTheme,
} from "@mui/material";
import CloseIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close";

export function BaseDialog({
  open,
  handleClose,
  title,
  children,
  sx,
}: {
  open: boolean;
  handleClose: () => void;
  title?: React.ReactNode;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  sx?: SxProps<Theme>;
}) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const fullScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("md"));

  return (
    <Dialog
      fullScreen={fullScreen}
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      maxWidth="lg"
      sx={{
        ...sx,
        "& .MuiDialog-container > .MuiPaper-root": {
          height: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "background.default",
          ...(sx as any)?.["& .MuiDialog-container > .MuiPaper-root"],
        },
        "& .MuiDialogContent-root": {
          flexGrow: 1,
          backgroundColor: "background.default",
          maxHeight: "80vh",
          marginBlock: 2,
          ...(sx as any)?.["& .MuiDialogContent-root"],
        },
        "& .dialogBox-Icon": {
          position: "absolute",
          right: (theme) => theme.spacing(2.5),
          top: (theme) => theme.spacing(1),
          ...(sx as any)?.["& .dialogBox-Icon"],
        },
      }}
    >
      {title && <DialogTitle>{title}</DialogTitle>}

      <IconButton onClick={handleClose} className="dialogBox-Icon" size="large">
        <CloseIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <DialogContent dividers>{children}</DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

I want to open multiple dialog concurrently like that:

[image]

**Save and add a subsequent task** button should call an API endpoint to save data and it should close current modal and open another dialog and this should go forever. There should not be an end.

I have searched on internet but I couldn't find good example for this.
How can I do that with this current generic DialogProvider?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the challenge. Once the user clicks `Save and add a subsequent task` the modal will closed and you call openModal again. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, correct. But in this usage `Save and add a subsequent task` button doesn't close the current modal only opens a new modal. I don't want that. It should close the current one and open a new one.

Comment: Can you show the BaseModal component code? Or better, can you demonstrate the issue in a live example using codesandbox or a similar tool?

Comment: I updated base question with BaseDialog code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm seeing only **one** modal that can be open or close. If I would see somewhere array of modals, multiple open modals would make sense but this is not the case. Is is possible to demonstrate the issue within a codesandbox so I could try to debug it?